# How do you get "this" look?

Tags: materials

I always see this style of 3D art that really stands out. They kind of look like toys, like the material looks unnatural yet appealing. Ill post some examples, you know it when you see it.

[image]
By Dimas NP

[image]
(Tried looking everywhere for the artist but I can find the name, sorry!)

[image]
by Julien Kaspar
This one is maybe closest to what im talking about.

Ive never really seen a tutorial on how this style is done so I hope someone can help

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what you like in these pictures is that the materials are somewhere between plastic, modeling clay and skin, which I guess is a mix between glossy and translucency. You could try with this: Mix *Diffuse* and *Glossy* nodes, with a *Fresnel* as factor, and mix this with a *Subsurface Scattering* which will give the translucency and lightness. For the second picture maybe he used an *Image Texture* for the skin (blushed cheeks), that he plugged into the *Diffuse*.

[image]

Comment: I tried it on something ive been working on and it didn't really come out close to it.

The texture I had on it got washed out and muddy and it doesn't have any AO in the cracks and that like white part in the thick areas

https://i.imgur.com/Edb83Nh.jpg

Comment: To me what you show looks rather like plastic, it might even not need Subsurface Scattering but just a mix between Diffuse and Glossy, but maybe someone will find something satisfying

Comment: oh it's ok   ;)  but what you show above has nothing to do with what I propose

Comment: I would recommend you to join Blender cloud, there is upcoming video tutorial about creating stylized characters from Julien which is great, see it here : https://cloud.blender.org/blog/introducing-rain